# Constructor inheritance questions

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototypejs, prototype-chain

I started reading about inheritance in constructors (everything is clear in classes) and ran into some problems and misunderstandings. Could you explain to me which code practices are normal and which ones should be avoided?

**1) Are these equivalent way to check whether object is instance of Parent?**

```
let Parent = function(a){
  this.a = a
}
let obj = new Parent()
console.log(obj.constructor === Parent ) // true
console.log(obj.__proto__ === Parent.prototype) // true
console.log(obj instanceof Parent) // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) ) // true
```

**2) Is there any difference between these two examples?**

```
function Shape() {
    this.checkedPoints = []
  }
function Rectangle(a){
    this.__proto__ = new Shape()
    this.a = a; 
  }

let m = new Rectangle("first")
let n = new Rectangle("second")
m.checkedPoints.push(1)
n.checkedPoints.push(2);

console.log(m.checkedPoints) // Array [ 1 ]
console.log(n.checkedPoints) // Array [ 2 ]
```

and

```
function Shape() {
    this.checkedPoints = [];
  }
  
function Rectangle(a) {
    Shape.apply(this);
    this.a = a;
}

let m = new Rectangle("first");
let n = new Rectangle("second");
m.checkedPoints.push(1);
n.checkedPoints.push(2);

console.log(m.checkedPoints); // Array [ 1 ]
console.log(n.checkedPoints); // Array [ 2 ]
```

**3) Why can't I access properties of Shape although m is instance of Shape????**

```
function Shape() {
    this.checkedPoints = [];
  }
  
  function Rectangle(a) {
    this.a = a;
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this.__proto__, Shape.prototype)
  }
  
  let m = new Rectangle("first");
  console.log(m instanceof Shape, m instanceof Rectangle) // true true
  console.log(m.a) //first
  m.checkedPoints.push(1) // m.checkedPoints is undefined
```

Comment: Please ask only a single question per post.

Comment: 1) No, they're not equivalent. `{}`, `Object.create(Parent.prototype)`, `{constructor: Parent}`, `new Child` and `Object.assign(object.create(Parent.prototype), {constructor: Parent})` (where `class Child extends Parent {}`) will all cause different results when used for `obj`.

Comment: 2) Yes, there is a difference. But don't use either. The first creates two instances per `new Rectangle` call (so `Object.getPrototypeOf(m) !== Object.getPrototypeOf(n)`), and the instances are not Rectangles (`m instanceof Rectangle` is false). The second version is better but does not have the rectangles inherit from `Shape` (`m instanceof Shape` is false).

Comment: 3) Because you never called the `Shape` constructor so it did not initialise the `m` instance. Also, you really should not modify the prototype object inside the constructor! `Object.setPrototypeOf(this.__proto__, Shape.prototype)` is the same as `Object.setPrototypeOf(Rectangle.prototype, Shape.prototype)`, no need to repeat that for every `new Rectangle` invocation - place it outside of the constructor function.